# Correctly rendering a Popup

Tags: react-native

I have been working on a project where when the user has clicked on a button, a popup renders. My popup actually shows but below elements in the page. Could someone help me figure out where what I could have done wrongly?

Comment: Can you post your code what you are tryng?

Comment: If you are using rn's [alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html), then it should appear instantly above all views. However if you are using a modal you should add it to the waay bottom of your view code in your render function as @GouxLord said. And finally it is always good to share some code.

Comment: _getEndRidePopup(){
            return this.state.endRidePopupShown && (
                    <Popup>
                        <ul className="b-end-ride-list">
                            <li>Option 1</li>
                            <li>Option 2</li>
                            <li>Option 3</li>
                            <li>Option 4</li>
                            <li><a onClick={this._toggleEndRidePopup} className="close-button">Close</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </Popup>
                );
        },

Answer (score 0):

By default elements are rendered bottom to
 top so you need to have your popups after the others elements in document tree.

An other way is to use [zIndex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#zindex) property